# Detect Auto Increment Column

Tags: mysql, pdo

How can I get the auto_increment column name from a table **(NOT THE LAST INSERT ID)**?

for example:

```
create table members (member_id int auto_increment, name char(50), primary key(member_id));
```

What can I do to get the `member_id` from table members.

I am making a php class, and I am going to add a method that will allow you to get this like this:

```
$members->findById(123);
```

It should know to find the auto increment column and build a query based on that then do the query.

Comment: But I don't need the insert id, I need the column name.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  This question was marked as a duplicate, but the other question is different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the column with

```
show columns from members where extra like '%auto_increment%'
```

The first column `Field` is your auto_increment column name.

```
$sql = "show columns from members where extra like '%auto_increment%'";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die($dbh->error());
$sth->execute() or die($dbh->error());
$row = $sth->fetch();
$column = $row['Field'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  column_name 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE    table_name = "members" 
AND     extra = "auto_increment";
```

Try this!

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this type of function as part of the Zend_Db component when I worked on the Zend Framework.  I found that accessing the INFORMATION_SCHEMA is too slow, so I had to use DESCRIBE instead.

Something like the following (but this is simplified code I just tested, not part of Zend Framework):

```
function getAutoIncColumn($table)
{
    global $dbh;

    $stmt = $dbh->query("DESCRIBE `$table`");
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      if (strstr($row["Extra"], "auto_increment")) {
        return $row["Field"];
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Problems with information schema slowness can be solved with:
 `set global innodb_stats_on_metadata=0;`

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin, thanks I know about that config variable.  It's a good workaround.  But it might not be set, and the PHP app may not have the SUPER privilege required to change global variables.

Comment: `set session innodb_stats_on_metadata=0;` for queries using information schema in that case.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin that variable cannot be changed per session.  It's a global variable only.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to prepare the statement dynamically based on the information_schema, then execute it.

```
PREPARE stmt FROM concat(
 'select * from members where ', 
 (select COLUMN_NAME 
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  where table_name='members' and EXTRA like '%auto_increment%'),
  '=?'
 );
EXECUTE stmt;
```